# ModelState.IsValid is false after Jquery Validation is true

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to create a simple create user page that contains a users details and a confirm password field.

I have a User view model and a User class:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public User AccountUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Compare("AccountUser.Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

[DisplayName("User Account")]
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When entering in mismatched data into the two password fields, the jQuery will successfully tell me  that the password fields to not match and the submit button will not fire back to my controller.

However if I match the two fields, the jQuery will pass its validation and the submit query will fire back to the controller. At that point my `ModelState.IsValid` is checked and it returns false citing "Could not find property AccountUser.Password" on the errors for the Password property.

I understand the separation of concerns pattern, however I am trying to understand why this code does not work.

Can someone explain why the modelstate is returning false after no jquery validation messages are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It may be something to do with your post back, so your client side validation is working, but the data is not being fully returned to your controller.

Put some breakpoints in your controller and check if its getting null values back for your User in your ViewModel.

Comment: I am seeing the object fully populated as soon as it gets back to the controller, with all values in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only can use `Compare` attribute like `[Compare("PropertyName")]`, not `[Compare("Object.PropertyName")]` - as the error says: `... cannot find the property Account.Password ...`.

You should change your model and your attribute like `[Compare("Password")]`

Comment: This will not work (I have tried), because the Password property does not exist in the view model itself, but only inside the child class.

Comment: @Jastill - I know this will not work! as I told: `You should change your model ...`

Comment: What I wish to know is why the JavaScript validation works but some magical behind the scenes ModelState validation will not. I would have thought that only one validation routine was required. If it passes the jQuery comparison match then the modelstate for that field should be without error.